# C++ wrapper function (macro) to access COM object properties

Tags: c++, properties, com, macros

I have a COM object with an interface containing a lots of properties defined in the following way:

```
[propget] HRESULT Width([out, retval] LONG *lValue);
```

To access such property from C++ I need to add a code like this:

```
LONG lValue;  
HRESULT hr = pInterface->get_Width(&lValue);  
if (FAILED(hr)) lValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

This block is not too long but when many properties are used, the code become not so good looking. Is there a way to separate property access code into some macro or template function to be able to use the properties directly, like this:

```
printf("The width of the object is %d", GET_OBJECT_PROPERTY(pInterace, Width, DEFAULT_VALUE));
```

UPD: VC2008 compiler is used to build the project

UPD: Thanks to all! Here is my solution:

```
template <class interface_type, class property_type>
property_type GetPropertyValue(interface_type* pInterface, HRESULT(STDMETHODCALLTYPE interface_type::*pFunc)(property_type*), property_type DefaultValue = 0)
{
  property_type lValue;

  HRESULT hr = (*pInterface.*pFunc)(&lValue);

  if (FAILED(hr)) 
    lValue = DefaultValue;
  return lValue;
}
```

which can be called as

```
LONG lVideoStreamCount = GetPropertyValue(pInfo, &IInterfaceName::get_VideoStreamCount);
```

I am still looking for a way to eliminate this 'IInterfaceName::' part from the call.

Comment: Look at the #import directive, it auto-generates wrappers from the type library.

Answer (score 0):

### [**#import "myInterface.tlb"**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx)

(As Hans already put in the comments. Really. I find COM in C++ unbearable without)

This generates - in the default setting - a high level wrapper. Properties like yous example are exposed through [__decspec(property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd%28VS.80%29.aspx), a compiler-specific extension:

```
LONG lValue = pInterface->Width;
```

---

[edit] more info:

For compiling .idl's, I disable the C header generation of MIDL (except proxy/stub generation, if needed).

With the default #import settings:

- You get high level wrappers that

  - turn FAILED(hr) into a `_com_error` exception
  - turn `[out, retval]` into a real return value,
  - exposes properties as if they were properties
  - give access to the "original" COM interface through  `raw_Method()`, `get_Property()` etc.
- GUID's are available via `__uuidof()`, e.g. `__uuidof(IMyInterface)` instead of `IID_IMyInterface`.
- all deninitions are in a namespace based on the name of the COM library

However, all these can be configured by #import attributes.

I put my .idl's in a separate project generating only the .tlb's, and I use the #imported headers both for implementing and consuming interfaces. This means you have to make soem adjustments to wizard-generated code, e.g. prefixing COM method implementations with `raw_`

Comment: It is interesting and can be helpful in some cases, but as I understood if property getter failed compiler will generate an exception. And exceptions are not welcomed in our company code :(

Comment: That's sad really. I can see (a very few isolated) reasons for avoiding exceptions, but more often than not that approach is misguided. -- The "comfortable" wrappers need some mechanism to indicate failure, and I don't see anything reasonable other than exceptions in that scenario.  --- You *could* trick the generated code into calling a callback, but what should happen, other than maybe terminating the program?